# javascript chainning return this from callback

Tags: javascript, callback, return, chaining

i've tried to get a return this from a callback, but i always get undefined.

here is the snipped

```
create: function(currentView, data){
    var itsMe = this; 
    this.thumbsWrapper = this.templates.wrapper().hide();
    currentView.append(this.thumbsWrapper);
    this.thumbsWrapper.fadeIn("fast", function(){
        return itsMe;                                                 
    });
},

var l = list().create(currentView); //need teh return that i can use chaining
```

the var l is now undefined, if i use the fadeIn with a callback...
if i dont use fadeIn with the callback it returns the obj

anyone an idea why?

Comment: Because the callback returns the value to where it was called, which is somewhere inside `.fadeIn`. It has no effect on the `create` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Felix Kling say is correct, you are not returning anything. If you want to return `itsMe` you will need to do:

```
create: function(currentView, data){
    var itsMe = this; 
    this.thumbsWrapper = this.templates.wrapper().hide();
    currentView.append(this.thumbsWrapper);
    this.thumbsWrapper.fadeIn("fast");
    return itsMe;    
}
```

Which should suffice if you want chaining.

If you want to get a reference to `itsMe` when the fadeout is finished, you will need to pass your own callback:

```
create: function(currentView, data, callback){
    var itsMe = this; 
    this.thumbsWrapper = this.templates.wrapper().hide();
    currentView.append(this.thumbsWrapper);
    this.thumbsWrapper.fadeIn("fast", function(){ 
        callback(itsMe);
    });  
}


list().create(function (that) {
    console.log("fade out complete");
    console.log("itsMe is", that);
});
```

And if you want to have a chaining pattern, which will execute the next function in the chain when fadeout is finished, you will need to pass not a reference to `this` but an object which can queue up commands, implement each command sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the object in the `create()` function, it is currently not returning anything:

```
create: function(currentView, data){
    var itsMe = this; 
    this.thumbsWrapper = this.templates.wrapper().hide();
    currentView.append(this.thumbsWrapper);
    this.thumbsWrapper.fadeIn("fast", function(){
        return itsMe;  //<--- this isn't going anywhere because you don't capture it                                               
    });
    return itsMe; //<------ return the object
},
```

Comment: Also note that because of the asynchronous nature of the animation functions, this function will return *as soon as possible*, i.e. as soon as the fade in animation is added to the animation queue.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens thats true but is OK since he isn't doing anything or modifying `itsMe` in the fadeIn complete call.

Comment: Agreed, I just noted that because it wasn't exactly clear *when* the OP expected the `create` function to return.