# Returning from a callback function

Tags: javascript, storage

I'm writing a basic wrapper for the Webkit Storage API (the new version of [this](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#reference) API) for me to use. My current problem with it is the `queryUsageAndQuota()` function.

My wrapper around that particular function originally looked like this:

```
self.pers.getQuota = function() {
    self.pers.queryUsageAndQuota(function(usage,quota) {
        return quota;
    });
}
// self is a reference to the top level of this 'wrapper'
```

Hence, I would have called `var quota = self.pers.getQuota();` and had the quota returned.

After that failed, I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258744/javascript-chainning-return-this-from-callback) and changed it so I used a user-defined callback instead. Now the function is this:

```
self.pers.getQuota = function(callback) {
    self.pers.queryUsageAndQuota(function(usage,quota) {
        callback.call(quota);
    });
}
```

However, executing this line:

```
self.pers.getQuota(function(quota) {
    console.log(quota);
});
```

shows `undefined` in the log. I can't figure out why, because when I execute the underlying function `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.queryUsageAndQuota()`, I get the right number out of it.

Comment: quota is an array? becouse if it is, make sense to use call. but if it isn't, just call `callback` as a normal function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.call` doesn't work like you think it does. Instead do `callback.call(null, quota)`.

The actual signature for both `Function.prototype.call` (and similarly for `apply`) is

```
 Function.prototype.call(valueOfThis, valueOfParam1, valueOfParam2, ...);
```

This is also why I often say that the `this` keyword in javascript is stupid and you should avoid using it. It simply is another parameter like all the others, You just don't get to specify a name for it. It's a vestige of javascript's creation when Netscape mandated that this Scheme-based language look like Java.

Incidentally, you could use the third way of invoking methods here. Simply

```
callback(quota);
```

This however has the side effect of making javascript take a guess at what you want `this` to be (the global `window` object in this case). As long as you don't use `this`, the simple syntax works great.

If you actually *really* want to return a value rather than passing a callback look into javascript promises. I can't tell you which one to use without knowing what environment you in and what libraries you're using but [jQuery has a good implementation in the Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: Complete vanilla if that helps. No libraries, using the API as described, Chrome, Windows 7.

Comment: Latest chrome [supports promises](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) natively if that's all that's the only browser that you need to worry about. Matter of fact, latest everything but IE seems to support them.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
self.pers.getQuota = function(callback) {
    self.pers.queryUsageAndQuota(function(usage,quota) {
        callback(quota);
    });
}
```

**Or**

```
self.pers.getQuota = function(callback) {
    self.pers.queryUsageAndQuota(function(usage,quota) {
        callback.call(/* an object as 'this'*/, quota);
    });
}
```

[Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

**Or**

```
self.pers.getQuota = function(callback) {
    self.pers.queryUsageAndQuota(function(usage,quota) {
        callback.apply(/* an object as 'this'*/, [quota]);
    });
}
```

[Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)